# solving non linear problems in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy

[in last equation i need to solve for q.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iReR3.png)  [Here is the problem from miranda feckler , I need to develop equivalent python code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zTPIz.png) If my function is based on many variables and i need to solve non linear root finding problem for only one variable then how will i write-

when i write all the three variable, I get following error

```
TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable
```

and when i write only one of variables-

i get error-

```
 TypeError: resid() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'p' and 'phi'
```

can anyone tell me my mistake and a better code for this.

Comment: Can you give us the mathematical representation of the equation for which you want the roots? Hint: You can use some Latex editor to make the representation, save it as an image (say as an .png or .jpg file), then edit your question to include that image.

Comment: And leave a comment for me so that I know you've done that.

Comment: @BillBell please look into my problem

Comment: You're satisfied with the answer from aquirdturtle then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`broyden1(resid(co, p_node, q), co)`
breaks because the term `resid(co, p_node, q)` gets evaluated (returning an array) before passing into the function.

`broyden1(resid, co)`
breaks because when broyden1 evaluates it calls resid(co) which is clearly not well defined. You want to be able to pass the initial guess as a single object (e.g. a tuple) in broyden1, so a simple solution is to just redefine resid to take in a tuple instead of three sepearate arguments, like so:

```
def resid(arg):
    c,p,phi = arg
    return p + (phi * c) * ((-1 / eta) * (p ** (eta + 1))) \
           - alpha * (np.sqrt(np.abs(phi * c))) - (phi * c) ** 2
c1 = scipy.optimize.broyden1(resid, (co, p_node, q))
```

Comment: Hi, i tried it but the problem with this is that c1 is length n=26 while resid gives problem of length 3n=78 and i am getting error -operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (78,) (26,) .
What can be done

Comment: Not sure. You should make sure resid evaluates correctly at a single point before using it in a solver like this, or else even if it doesn't throw errors it's hard to be positive there isn't a numerical bug somewhere. Try evaluating resid((1,1,1)) and resid(([1,2],1,1)) (a) using the code and (b) **by hand**, to make sure the values match, and to make sure the function handles arrays correctly. I'm guessing the latter will return 6 results. If this is the case, try breaking the `return ...` statement into pieces and looking at them to see where things are going wrong.